# Listening to async upload task to handle loading state

Tags: typescript, react-native, asynchronous, google-cloud-storage, loading

I'm trying to set a loading state according to the state of sending. If the image is sent I will simply insert a loading indicator. Although whenever the task is running, I'm receiving a done (.then()) before the task actually finishes, and the loading indeicator doesnt work as expected:

The task:

```
export async function storeImage(uri: string, description: string) {
  const reference = ref(storage, `posts/${auth.currentUser!.uid}/${uuid.v4()}`);

  const blob: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
    };
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

  const uploadTask: any = uploadBytesResumable(reference, blob);

  uploadTask.on(
    'state_changed',
    (snapshot: any) => {
      const progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case 'paused':
          // console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case 'running':
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    },
    (error: any) => {
      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
      console.log('Storage error', error);
      blob.close();
    },
    () => {
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        await addImageReferenceToFirestore({ url: downloadURL, description });
      });

      blob.close();
    }
  );
}
```

if I insert an await on `const uploadTask: any = uploadBytesResumable(reference, blob);`
I get this error, and it stays loading forever:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...uploadTask.on...')]
```

This is my component:

```
export function Post({ navigation, ...rest }: any) {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  async function createPost() {
    setLoading(true);
    await storeImage(rest.route.params.images[0], description).then(() => console.log('done'));
    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      {loading ? (
        <Circle size={RFValue(25)} indeterminate={true} color="red" />
      ) : (
        <CreateBar
          text={i18n.t('createPost.title')}
          iconName="CreatePost"
          onPressIcon1={() => navigation.goBack()}
          onPressIcon2={() => createPost()}
        />
      )}
      <ContainerDescription>
        <ImageContainer>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: rest.route.params.images[0] }}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: 8 }}
          />
        </ImageContainer>

        <TextAreaContainer>
          <InputText
            placeholder={i18n.t('createPost.describe')}
            onChangeText={(newText: string) => setDescription(newText)}
          />
        </TextAreaContainer>
      </ContainerDescription>

      <LightDivider />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving a `done` from the `console.log` before the task finishes, because you're not actually awaiting for the task to finish. You are just awaiting the `blob` part.

If you just want to get to the final result of the uploaded image URL, without displaying any progress, then you should also await for the  `uploadTask.on` to finish. Wrap `uploadTask.on` inside a `Promise`, `resolve` on successfully uploading the image and `reject` on errors:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  uploadTask.on(
    'state_changed',
    (snapshot: any) => {
      const progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case 'paused':
          // console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case 'running':
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    },
    (error: any) => {
      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
      console.log('Storage error', error);
      blob.close();
      reject(error);
    },
    () => {
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
        .then(async (downloadURL) => {
          console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
          try {
            await addImageReferenceToFirestore({ url: downloadURL, description });
          } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
          }

          resolve();
        })
        .catch((err) => reject(err));

      blob.close();
    },
  );
});
```

And you should also add a `try/catch/finally` block to your `createPost` function. Otherwise if the `Promise` is rejected, the `setLoading(false)` would never be executed:

```
async function createPost() {
  try {
    setLoading(true);
    await storeImage(rest.route.params.images[0], description);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}
```